# RegisterType (typeof) vs RegisterType

Tags: c#, .net, unity-container, ioc-container

Do the following two pieces of code do exactly the same thing?

```
.RegisterType<ICrmService, CrmService>()
```

and

```
.RegisterType(typeof(ICrmService), typeof(CrmService))
```

Comment: the title of your questions speaks about RegisterType and RegisterInstance. How is the content of the question related ?

Comment: thank you, ive updated the title

Comment: yes they do the same thing

Answer (score 2):

In short: yes they do.

Just look at the source code: https://unity.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#source/Unity/Src/UnityContainerExtensions.cs

The generic method:

```
public static IUnityContainer RegisterType<TFrom, TTo>(this IUnityContainer container, params InjectionMember[] injectionMembers) where TTo : TFrom
{
    Guard.ArgumentNotNull(container, "container");
    return container.RegisterType(typeof(TFrom), typeof(TTo), null, null, injectionMembers);
}
```

The non-generic method:

```
public static IUnityContainer RegisterType(this IUnityContainer container, Type from, Type to, params InjectionMember[] injectionMembers)
{
    Guard.ArgumentNotNull(container, "container");
    return container.RegisterType(from, to, null, null, injectionMembers);
}
```

Comment: The advantage of the generic overload is the fact that the C# compiler will do the type checking for you (at compile time) instead of letting the code fail at runtime when `TFrom` is not assignable from `TTo`.